# What sites support Garmin Edge 200 .FIT format?

Tags: bike-computer, gps

I'm wondering what sites support uploading .FIT (from a Garmin Edge 200) files for analysis and mapping? I know that Garmin Connect does, but I'd like to evaluate other sites that does what Connect does.

Thanks very much.

Comment: strava.com, runkeeper.com, mapmyride.com, ridewithgps.com. Some of those require the browser plugin.

Comment: @freiheit: Convert that to an answer.

Comment: @zenbike: What I wrote was too short and uninformative to be a proper answer, and I didn't feel like putting in the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@freiheit answered above, but I highly recommend strava.com as the added component of segments and battling it out with my friends over a section of road whether or not we are riding at the same time, or even if we are, seeing how much time I took back (or gave up) on a hill is pretty cool.

With a paid membership they add additional ride analysis, such as HR and power. With your entered body weight and bicycle weight it will estimate your power and have found it to be a little off of my measured power, but it is always off by the same, so you can use it for trends (up or down) but wouldn't compare it to other cyclists too much.

I prefer it so much that I am now logging all my rides, runs, swims and other workouts, basically using it as my training log.

Another option (not a website though) is SportTracks from Zone Five Software, download this onto your computer and import your rides, your data on your computer. I've used their free version and have to manually upload/import my .FIT files. I think the newer version will read right off your device.

Comment: Thank you. I took a look at all of them and found RideWithGPS.com the best for me. I really like the ability to create my own routes and upload them to my bike GPS.

Comment: Checkout Bike Route Toaster to create routes and upload to your device too. http://bikeroutetoaster.com/Course.aspx

Comment: +1 for sporttracks for road warrior without internet access and only a laptop!